# Can I package prebuilt binary exe inside MSIX package?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, windows-store-apps, msix

I have a console app written in C++, and I want to put it inside [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/) package to be able to distribute it to my users (and potentially put on Windows Store). I manually compiled the app to `MyApp.exe` file, and now I want to create MSIX package that includes this `.exe` file. Is it possible to do it with MSIX? So far I have been using [Windows Application Packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) in Visual Studio, but it seems you must add a reference to your project in order to pack it (which I don't have, because I just have a binary file `MyApp.exe`). Any ideas how can I add a binary file to MSIX package or maybe some alternative way to package C++ app inside MSIX?

So far the only option I can see is to use `MSI` technology instead of `MSIX`, but I'd prefer to use a newer installation technology.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? Currently running into the same problem.

Comment: @ThomasVos No I didn't. It was an educational project, and I didn't bother to spend too much time on it. Maybe you can check out `MakeAppx.exe` proposed by Reilly Wood

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am currently looking into `MakeAppx.exe` which seems to work for me. However, packing resources and signing is more complicated since it is not possible to use Visual Studio anymore for this. But I guess this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [MakeAppx.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-) tool can package arbitrary files into an MSIX package, it's probably the simplest way to accomplish this.

I tried to do something similar with Windows Application Packaging in Visual Studio a while back and gave up; the VS tooling for MSIX is buggy and poorly documented in my experience.